# Add value from foreign key table depending on name

Tags: sql, key

I want to have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE buildings
(
    ID int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    city_ID int NOT NULL REFERENCES(cities),
    name char(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE cities
(
    ID int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name char(30) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO cities (name) VALUES ('Katowice')
```

Now I need that when I write:

```
INSERT INTO buildings (city_ID,name) values (1,'bahnhof')
```

makes the same effect that when I write:

```
INSERT INTO buildings VALUES ('Katowice','bahnhof')
```

My purpose is that when I want to add building to a city, I think about city name, not its ID in cities table. But sometimes I remember ID, and then I prefer to use ID. Is it possible without creating a procedure?

I am thinking about appropriate procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addbuilding
    @city_ID int,
    @name char
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO buildings (city_ID,name) VALUES (@city_ID,@name)

END
```

But as we can see above, @city_ID can be only int. Something like union in C++ could be a good solution, but is it possible in SQL?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think there isn't a way to do it without a procedure.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I am thinking about procedure now. How can I do it? I will edit my post and describe my problem more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if SQL procedures support union similarly to C++ as you ask, but my suggestion would be a rather simple one: two procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_building_by_city_id
    @city_ID int,
    @name char
etc

CREATE PROCEDURE add_building_by_city_name
    @city_name char,
    @name char
etc
```

And then you could use whichever one you need. Of course that the second procedure would need a simple `SELECT` first, to find the city by its name and retrieve its ID.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. How about making refenrence not from city ID but from city name? I tried it, but I had not succeeded - I had some information about conversion problems or something like that.

Comment: Don't do it. You should always avoid having indexes (particularly keys) as strings. Strings require much more effort to compare than integers, thus it can compromise query processing when it envolves references.